# Connect a modem to a router through a patch panel?

Tags: networking, router, modem, cat6, cat5e

I currently have my router next to my modem which is in the far corner of my basement. I would like to buy a 16 port patch panel and 16 port switch to organize and manage my 9 runs. My questionis since I plan to move my wireless router to the main floor, and smack dab in the middle of my house will I need to directly run wire from my modem to my router, or for future proof run a line from my modem to my patch panel and run from the patch pannel to the router. Also  should I do the same to backfeed another cable from my router port back to the switch or the patch pannel that is patched over the the switch so if in the future I could move the router? Is this the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your router connects to the modem via a CAT5 cable. If so just run CAT5 from Modem location to patch panel and cable into Router. I've done this in many installations and left the Fibre modem near the entry point and patched RJ45 into patch panel at the desired location.

Alternately, you can also patch a ADSL line into a patch panel, you only need to use 2 cores (leave the rest in case you want to move router back) just use the RJ45 head for out and RJ11 for into the Router.